# how to use .each or .map to create multiple object in protractor

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

I'm trying to create an array of a custom object that requires an ElementFinder as a parameter.

The custom object, StatusObj, takes an ElementFinder object.

The code I'm trying to do create my objects and return that array looks like this:

```
function getStatusObjs() {
    var arr;

    arr = $$('li').each(function(el) {
        return new StatusObj(el);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

This doesn't work. It locks up and times out or runs out of space. I've tried '.map()' and I've tried putting `arr = new StatusObj(el);` but, of course, arr isn't in scope (for lack of a better term) within the .each function.

Update for Alexce:

Here is the stack trace I get when I try your solution:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  118309 ms: Mark-sweep 1254.4 (1434.1) -> 1239.4 (1434.1) MB, 2124.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  120614 ms: Mark-sweep 1239.4 (1434.1) -> 1239.4 (1434.1) MB, 2305.0 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  122702 ms: Mark-sweep 1239.4 (1434.1) -> 1239.4 (1434.1) MB, 2088.9 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  124818 ms: Mark-sweep 1239.4 (1434.1) -> 1239.4 (1434.1) MB, 2115.1 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x30c99fec9fa9 <JS Object>
    1: get stack [native messages.js:595] [pc=0x32edf1d73957] (this=0x82e2251cb1 <a RangeError with map 0x206aaf5b8ae9>)
    3: resolve_ [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1115] [pc=0x32edf1dfdbe5] (this=0x82e2247b99 <a Promise with map 0x206aaf58ff81>,newState=0x29909e1edd89 <String[8]: rejected>,newValue=0x82e2251cb1 <a RangeError with map 0...

FAbort trap: 6
```

Is this a problem with my object creation code or that I'm not handling the promise correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently bug reported for this - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2227

I did dirty hack that works for me while i waiting for that bug to be fixed.

```
class ArrayContainer {
    /**
     * Special wrapper around array element finder,
     * but wraps returned elements to provided classToWrap.
     *
     * TODO: Find way to wrap elements with $$('div').map(elem => new WrappedElem(elem))
     * Currently bug is reported - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2227
     * @param arrayFinder
     * @param classToWrap
     */
    constructor (arrayFinder, classToWrap) {
        this.classToWrap = classToWrap;
        this.arrayFinder = arrayFinder;
    }

    get(index) {
        return new this.classToWrap(this.arrayFinder.get(index), this.arrayFinder.ptor_);
    }

    first() {
        return new this.classToWrap(this.arrayFinder.first(), this.arrayFinder.ptor_);
    }

    last() {
        return new this.classToWrap(this.arrayFinder.last(), this.arrayFinder.ptor_);
    }

    /**
     * Wraps .map() function, so provided function will receive wrapped object as first param, not ElementFinder.
     */
    map(func) {
        return this.arrayFinder.map((elem, index) => {
            // No return, since i am not sure that it will not fail with this bug -
            // https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2227
            func(new this.classToWrap(elem, this.arrayFinder.ptor_), index)
        });
    }
    /**
     * Wraps .filter() function, so provided function will receive wrapped object as first param, not ElementFinder.
     */
    filter(func) {
        let filtered = this.arrayFinder.filter((elem, index) => {
            return func(new this.classToWrap(elem, this.arrayFinder.ptor_), index)
        });
        return new ArrayContainer(filtered, this.classToWrap);
    }

    count() {
        return this.arrayFinder.count();
    }
}
```

Notice .map() function does not return anything in my hack

Usage is -

```
var checkboxes = ArrayContainer($$('.checkbox'), Checkbox);
checkboxes.first() // returns Checkbox object, not ElementFinder
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`map()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
function getStatusObjs() {
    return $$('li').map(function(el) {
        return new StatusObj(el);
    });
}
```

Now, the result of `getStatusObjs()` call would be a *promise* that would be resolved into an array of `StatusObj` objects:

```
getStatusObjs().then(function (objs) {
    console.log(objs);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a RangeError.  I've updated my question with the error.  I've verified my selector is accurate. `$$('li').count()` returns a value of 2.

Comment: @Machtyn okay, sounds like something happening inside the `StatusObj` code that you have not shown.